# How to count elements repetation in an array list?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, transactions, apriori

```
if(Collections.frequency(ItemSet, distinctItemsList) >= support) {
    ItemList.addAll(ItemSet);
    FrequentItem1.put(ItemList, Collections.frequency(ItemSet, distinctItemsList));
    System.out.println(FrequentItem1);
}
```

the above code is just repeating the transaction instead of giving item followed by frequency

> `ItemList` is the array list of individual transactions

TID. ItemList

100. Tylenol,Thermometer
101. water,Milk,Battery

> `ItemSet` is an array list with elements like Tylenol, Thermometer,
>   Battery etc..i.e the Main function looks like this

```
try {
    Statement statement= connection.createStatement();
    String sql="Select distinct TID from transaction";
    ResultSet SetTid= statement.executeQuery(sql);
    while(SetTid.next()) {
        int initialTID= SetTid.getInt("TID");
        TID.add(initialTID);
    }
    System.out.println("TID  Items");
    for(int initialTID : TID) {
        String sqlitem="Select ItemSet from transaction where TID="+ initialTID;
        ResultSet setItem= statement.executeQuery(sqlitem);
        while(setItem.next()) {
            String items= setItem.getString("ItemSet");
            //System.out.println("&&&&&&&&"+ items);
            ItemList.add(items);
            ItemSet=Arrays.asList(items.split(","));

            noOfTransaction++;
            System.out.println(initialTID+":"+ items);
            //System.out.println(initialTID+":"+ ItemList);
        }

        for(String items : ItemSet) {
            System.out.println("&&&&>>"+ items);
            if(! distinctItemsList.contains(items)) {
                distinctItemsList.add(items);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No of transaction"+ noOfTransaction);
    }
}
```

> `DistinctItem` list is an array list that contains unique items.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java-8, below should generate hashmap with word and it's frequency-

```
Map<String, Long> collect = wordsList.stream().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
```